# How can I use two sequences as default based on another status column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Assume I have a table structured like this

```
CREATE TABLE Printout
(
  ID INT ,
  TypeID INT ,--TypeID references Type table
  PrintoutNumber INT
)

CREATE TABLE [Type] ( ID INT, Code NVARCHAR(5) )
```

and two sequences

```
CREATE SEQUENCE FirstSequence
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1 ;

CREATE SEQUENCE SecondSequence
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1 ;
```

What I want to do is add the sequences as default value for PrintoutNumber based on the value of TypeID in Printout table by calling NEXT VALUE FOR before inserting a row.

For example:

- IF TypeID = 1 --> PrintoutNumber = Next VALUE FOR FirstSequence
- IF TypeID = 2 --> PrintoutNumber = Next VALUE FOR SecondSequence

Code:

```
CASE 
   WHEN TypeID = 1 
      THEN NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.FirstSequence 
      ELSE NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.SecondSequence 
END AS PrinutoutNumber
```

What method/approach can be used to determine the same result?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What a strange scenario. I have to say this has the earmarks of a design that went left of center. You could probably create a scalar function to get the next value based on the value the input parameter. Then you could use that function as the default from your column. But remember this is only a default. Unless you have other mechanisms in place there would be no reason it couldn't be changed.

Comment: @SeanLange i agree with you

Comment: This is the best approach. Instead of using stored procedure. Thanks @SeanLange

Answer (score 0):

```
create procedure printout_insert
(
    @id int,
    @TypeId int
)
as
    declare @printNumber int;
    if @TypeId = 1 
    begin 
        set @printNumber = NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.FirstSequence;
    end;
    else if @TypeId = 2
    begin 
        set @printNumber = NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.SecondSequence;
    end;

    insert into printout
    (
        id,
        TypeId,
        PrintoutNumber
    )
    values
    (
        @id,
        @TypeId,
        @printNumber
    )
```

--insert rows

```
exec printout_insert 1,1
exec printout_insert 1,2
exec printout_insert 1,1
exec printout_insert 1,2
exec printout_insert 1,1
exec printout_insert 1,2
exec printout_insert 1,1
exec printout_insert 1,2
exec printout_insert 1,1
exec printout_insert 1,2
exec printout_insert 1,1
exec printout_insert 1,2
exec printout_insert 1,1

select * from printout order by typeid, PrintoutNumber
```

--results
1   1   1
1   1   2
1   1   3
1   1   4
1   1   5
1   1   6
1   1   7
1   2   1
1   2   2
1   2   3
1   2   4
1   2   5
1   2   6